# Wicked PDF is not able to pick the font in rails 4.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, base64, font-face, wicked-pdf

```
I tried almost all the available option, but my font is not included in generated PDF file. 
I tried base64 bit solution , converting css files to .scss and many more.
```

Everything is defined and pre compiled under assets.rb , application.rb.Please let me know if there is anything I am missing. I followed the solutions http://apleroy.com/posts/custom-pdf-fonts-with-wicked_pdf-and-heroku but in vain. Sample Code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Light';
  src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,T1RUTw..)
}

.custom_font {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro ExtraLight';
}
```

This is the CSS code sample I am using

Basic Layout

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "filename"-%>
  </head>
  <style>
      @font-face {
          font-family: 'proximanova';     
          src:url(data:font/truetype;;charset=utf-8;base64, AAA.....);
      }
  </style>
  <body >

      <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I earlier included the font-face in filename.css but did not work.

Comment: hope you did this `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "documents"` ?

Comment: Yes I did this wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "filename"

Comment: can you please post the layout please

Comment: Please post it on your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, I had font "fontname" and its sub classes as regular light lighter etc. Earlier I was using **font-family: 'fontname'** which was not rendered correct I guess.

When I used **font-family: 'fontname regular'** it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try absolute path to your_font.ttf

```
src: url('file:///path/to/your_font.ttf') format('truetype')
```

Comment: I tried this but PDF file is not taking the font specified.